# How to set default Sign-In options to PIN after remote desktop connection closed in WIN8

Tags: windows-8, remote-desktop, user-accounts, login

I create a PIN to login my windows account, And the default sign-in option is PIN when win8 startup

But the sign-in option switch to Password when I connected this computer via Remote Desktop

I don't like that, is there any way to set default Sign-In options to PIN ?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am having same issue with Windows 10 now.